# How can I use Flash Player now that it's no longer supported?

Tags: adobe-flash

I know that Adobe Flash Player is discontinued for Android devices, but is there an alternative way to continue using Flash on an Android device?

I have the APK of Flash Player 10, but I would like to use the most recent version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.flashplayer) won't play ball, you can download the Flash Player APK from Adobe [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html#flash_player_archives).

Direct download links:

- For Android 2.x and 3.x: [Flash Player 11.1 for Android 2.x and 3.x (11.1.111.73)](https://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/installers/archive/android/11.1.111.73/install_flash_player_pre_ics.apk)
- For Android 4.0+: [Flash Player 11.1 for Android 4.0 (11.1.115.81)](https://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/installers/archive/android/11.1.115.81/install_flash_player_ics.apk)

**Warning: Those versions are pretty old (2013) and are no longer supported by Adobe. Therefore installing it may make your device vulnerable to attacks from the Internet.**