# How do I play Flash websites on my Samsung Galaxy S3?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, adobe-flash

Is there a way to use flash-based sites on Android? A browser? Radical app? I want to play videos on this site: 
http://www.onf.ca/explorer-tous-les-films

OS: 4.1.1

Comment: One of the answers on http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32948/how-can-i-use-flash-player-now-that-its-no-longer-supported may help.

Comment: @DanHulme answers there are for Gingerbread. Are you sure they work for JellyBean as well?

Comment: No. Nor am I sure they won't. That's why I said they *may* help. I hope the OP can confirm either way.

Comment: OK -- so I've added a solution that *should* work on JB. Though I didn't try it myself, as I have no need :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it's okay to answer my own but I thought it might be useful to others.  I found these looking around more: [Photon browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appsverse.photon) and [Puffin browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cloudmosa.puffinFree).  Both play Flash sites without all the complicated installation of Adobe.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted links to the apps you mentioned. Please use the link tag. :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a [HowTo at MakeUseOf.Com](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-install-flash-on-your-android-jelly-bean-tablet-or-phone/) describing how to install Adobe flash player on JellyBean. Excerpt:

1. Enable [unknown-sources](/questions/tagged/unknown-sources) on your device
2. Grab the [`.apk` for flash player from XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1774336) and save/copy it to your SDCard
3. Use a file manager (such as e.g. [ES File Explorer File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop)), navigate to the place you've stored the `.apk`, and tap the file once. This starts the installer.

Once the installation is finished, you should be able to play flash again. However, not every browser might support it. The very same article mentions how to enable flash support in Firefox:

> Open Firefox, tap the menu button and open Settings > Plugins and choose Enabled.

That way you should be able to use it with your favorite websites.

Comment: Oh no, I don't have an SD card.  Why doesn't Android support Flash, anyway?

Comment: Not even an internal SDCard? Your device certainly has a local place to copy stuff to.

Comment: Oh, yes the internal one I have....I thought SD always meant external.

Comment: Yeah, one should think a card is a card. But manufacturers think otherwise, obviously :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Install [Adobe Flash Player for Android](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4675670#4675670).
2. Use [Boat Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.boatbrowser.free) as your Android browser. Enable Flash via `Settings > Page content settings > Enable flash/plug-ins`.

This is what I did to enable Flash on my Samsung Galaxy S4. No luck with stock browser and Dolphin.

Comment: Any stability issues?

Comment: @verve Nope. It's works as expected. I tried a Dolphin beta version which allegedly had Flash support, but it didn't work. Boat Browser is your best bet. I'm using it (and Dolphin too!)