# Adobe flash for Asus Transformer TF700T

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, asus-eee-pad-transformer, adobe-flash

Does anyone know if the Adobe flash player will be available for Android devices any time soon? I have Android 4.0 Ice cream sandwich. On ASUS Transformer TF700T. I can watch movies, videos and only play some games that don't require Adobe. Someone, Anyone. Please Help!

Comment: See also: [How can I use Flash Player now that it's no longer supported?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/32948)

Comment: See also: [Is Adobe Flash deprecated with regards to Android Devices and Apps?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/39751)

Comment: There are several other related questions in the [tag:adobe-flash] tag.

Answer (score 2):

Adobe Flash fot Android has been discontinued and all official methods of installing it have been removed. This is mainly due to problems in security, performance and stability, but the rise of HTML5 has also played its part. You can find more info from [here](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/08/availability-of-adobes-flash-browser-plugin-discontinued-on-android/) or [here](http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2012/06/flash-player-and-android-update.html).